# how to get information back after saving changes with Entity Framework and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

As the title suggests how can I get information back after saving changes with Entity Framework to sql in MVC.

I have a create method and I wanted to find out, if when a user saves a post how could I get the ID of the saved post back in the same view?

```
    // GET: /Post/Create
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create(Post post)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Posts.Add(post);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Assuming the `Post` has a property called `Id`, then after `SaveChanges()` has executed, `post.Id` will be set to the value the SQL server assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've saved an entity in the context `SaveChanges()`. The `ID` property on the poco itself should be set by the entity framework.

Look at `post.Id` after saving and it will be there!

If you are POSTing something other than the Post object with the form, you need to change the action method signature to have some kind of object for it to bind to, then save changes:

```
public ActionResult Create(Post post, OtherPartialViewItem item)
```

then

```
db.OtherPartialViewItem.Add(item); db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yeah but I plan to have a partial view savechanges to a different table, how would this effect that?

Comment: @KirstyWhite your comment here is suggesting that you are doing something other than the code you posted about in your question.  If you have some other view you are trying to work with, you should include the code you are actually concerned with.

Comment: @Claies "plan to" and "how would" do not indicate more code. I am asking if this would effect the results of said plan. If I had a partial view of which its job was to save something to another table, would this effect the main view results for post.Id or would I still have access to post.Id because the partial was a different table?

Comment: you are asking if the answer would be different if your code were different.  There isn't a way to know that for certain, but Entity Framework isn't going to change, so it's unlikely.

Comment: I updated my answer to try and help, even though your follow-up question is vague.

Comment: Yeah I seen the update +1 from me for the answer thanks